# How to extract fields' data from Ajax MVC action call?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

Here's the code:

1) MVC controller:

```
public DiagramData GetDiagramData()
{
    return new DataBindingHelper().GetData();
}
```

2) Data helper:

```
public class DataBindingHelper
{
    public DiagramData GetData()
    {
        DiagramData diagramData = new DiagramData();
        return diagramData;
    }
}

public class DiagramData
{
    public string From
    {
        get { return "Moscow"; }
    }

    public string To
    {
        get { return "Saint Petersburg"; }
    }

    public string Color
    {
        get { return "Red"; }
    }

    public int Thick
    {
        get { return 2; }
    }
}
```

3) Java Script:

```
function initDataBinding() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        //url: '@Url.Action("GetDiagramData", "Home")'
        url: '/Home/GetDiagramData'
    }).done(function (data) {
        //data = JSON.stringify(data);
        //alert(data.From);
    });
```

Comment: Is that API controller? or normal?

Comment: It's normal MVC controller.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's normal conroller it should be on server side:

```
public JsonResult GetDiagramData()
{
    return Json(new DataBindingHelper().GetData(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

On client side:

```
function initDataBinding() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/Home/GetDiagramData'
    }).done(function (data) {
        alert(data.From); //<- this line should work
    });
```

Comment: It doesn't work. After AJAX call goes another JavaScript library: var $ = go.GraphObject.make;

Comment: Excuse me, I'm not sure what you mean.